# Drawbacks of a high hibernate.jdbc.batch_size setting

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I increased the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` parameter to 50. This makes batch processings in our application a lot faster, which is great. Do I need to expect any drawbacks for the "regular" tasks of the application? The application responds to web requests and uses a single database connection per request. Most of the requests read only from the database, some requests save a few objects (but not hundreds).

Thank you very much for sharing your experiences.

Comment: In my experience, 50 is still in the "very reasonnable" range. Never noticed any adverse effect. I guess the only thing to watch would be memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` parameter determines how many statements are send to the database in one call. Having to many statements (a higher number) could result in either an OutOfMemoryException or a timeout on the transaction, when doing multiple statements in a transaction.

With webrequests you usually have less statements in a transaction. This setting shouldn't influence these transactions.

Depending on which part of the documentation you read, anywhere between 10 and 50 [Hibernate 3.3 chapter 13](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) or 5 and 30 [Hibernate 3.3 chapter 3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html) is reasonable / recommended.